# Query data with partial string match using GraphQL + Apollo client in Javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql, realm, apollo-client

I have the following query:

```
function useAllOrders(ownerId, storeId) {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(
    gql`
      query getOrders($ownerId: String!) {
        orders(query: { owner_id: $ownerId }) {
          _id
          // ... field list              
        }
      }
    `,
    { variables: { ownerId: `owner_id=${ownerId}&store_id=${storeId}` } }
  );
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch tasks: ${error.message}`);
  }
  const orders = data?.orders ?? [];
  return { orders, loading };
}
```

What I need to do is being able to query the order just by owner if storeId is null|undefined. That means that I should be able to do a partial find with owner_id=${ownerId}%. How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you intend for your `ownerId` variable to be a concatenation of owner and storedId? typically ownerId would be its own graphql variable.

Comment: This is realm and I use a concatenated ownerId so it can be partitioned correctly in different devices.

Comment: @MarianoL You mean https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/? And you didn't build/design the GraphQL API yourself?

Comment: No, just using the graphql api from realm sync.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ownerId` variable is a composite variable (odd) then

```
{ variables: { ownerId: `owner_id=${ownerId}&store_id=${storeId}` } }
```

would become

```
{ variables: { ownerId: `owner_id=${ownerId}${storeId ? `&store_id=${storeId}` : ''}` } }
```

You just need a conditional check when creating the variable's value.

Comment: but the value in the record will be set. So that wont work because it will look for:

owner_id=XXXX when the value is owner_id=XXXXX&store_id=YYYYYY

That's why I need to do a partial match. Something similar to SQL with owner_id like 'XXXXX%'

Comment: not quite sure what you're asking? partial matching is a backend concern?